# Insert Values into a Dictionary From a DF Column - Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, dataframe

I have a list of values that I am trying to match with a column of a pandas `df` and then would like to create a dictionary that will have list values as keys and then dictionary values from a different column from the data frame.

This is how I have my list:

```
sample_list = [101,105,112]
```

My Data Frame:

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame([[101, "NJ"], [105, "CA"],[111, "MO"], [101, "NJ"], [112, "NB"], [101, "NJ"], [105, "CA"]], \
                         columns=["Col1", "Col2"])
```

looks like this,

```
    Col1    Col2
0   101     NJ
1   105     CA
2   111     MO
3   101     NJ
4   112     NB
5   101     NJ
6   105     CA
```

Now, I am trying to iterate list values (which are keys of my `new_dict`)and match them with `Col1` and if they match I would like to extract `Col2` values as my dictionary values. This is how I have my code so far,

```
new_dict = {}
for value in sample_list:
    for i in sample_df['Col1']:
        if value == i:
            new_dict[value] = [i for i in sample_df['Col2']]
```

However, my `new_dict` looks like this,

```
{101: ['NJ', 'CA', 'MO', 'NJ', 'NB', 'NJ', 'CA'],
 105: ['NJ', 'CA', 'MO', 'NJ', 'NB', 'NJ', 'CA'],
 112: ['NJ', 'CA', 'MO', 'NJ', 'NB', 'NJ', 'CA']}
```

I need my output like this,

```
{101: ['NJ'],
 105: ['CA'],
 112: ['NB']}
```

How can I get to my desired output? Any help would be nice.

Comment: Why do you need the values in `new_dict` to be lists?

Comment: @NickD it doesn't have to be a list, i thought of putting into a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
new_dict = {i: [sample_df[sample_df['Col1']==i]['Col2'].values[0]] for i in sample_list}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Alt 1

If you insist here is another solution that should be efficient by using `isin()` to create a mask used to filter away not desired rows.

```
m = sample_df['Col1'].isin(sample_list)
sample_df[m].drop_duplicates().groupby('Col1')['Col2'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Returns: `{101: ['NJ'], 105: ['CA'], 112: ['NB']}`

*note: if there are more non-unique combos they will be in the list too*. Use: `{k:[v] for k,v in sample_df[m].groupby('Col1')['Col2'].first().items()}` if you only want the first.

---

#### Alt 2

If you are going for list items but not all why not just the values?

```
m = sample_df['Col1'].isin(sample_list)
sample_df[m].set_index('Col1')['Col2'].to_dict()
```

Returns: `{101: 'NJ', 105: 'CA', 112: 'NB'}`

---

#### Alt 3

**or** if you want all the items:

```
m = sample_df['Col1'].isin(sample_list)
sample_df[m].groupby('Col1')['Col2'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Returns: `{101: ['NJ', 'NJ', 'NJ'], 105: ['CA', 'CA'], 112: ['NB']}`